# save: on a NSManagedObjectContext not working

Tags: ios, core-data

In a navigation controller, I go from view controller 1 to view controller 2.

View Controller 1 is a table view controller tied to a FetchedResultsController. It fetches data from a specific context and displays it. I then segue to view controller 2 if a row is tapped. While segueing, I set a particular NSManagedObject property of view controller 2 using the data I have in view controller 1.

Now, in view controller 2 I am able to show data using the NSManagedObject property and then also make changes to it and perform a save:. When I go back to view controller 1 , the change is reflected. However, if I re-launch the app it is not being reflected any more in any of the view controllers.

This is how I am doing the save.

```
- (void)hiddenAttributeSwitchSlid:(UISwitch *)sender
{
    [self.workoutType.managedObjectContext performBlock:^{
        self.workoutType.workoutHiddenByDefault = [NSNumber numberWithBool:sender.isOn];
        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![self.workoutType.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"There was an error in saving to context - %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"No error");
        }
    }];
}
```

workoutType is a NSManagedObject which is set in the prepareForSegue: before segueing to this view controller.

Even if I do not use the performBlock:, it doesn't work.

PS - I know questions of this kind have been asked before. I browsed through them, but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in your code at the start of your SwitchSlid, can you observe the value of your NSManagedObjectContext (self.workoutType.managedObjectContext) and verify that you actually have a pointer to one?

Comment: What log message are you getting? You didn't indicate whether you actually got an error back from `save:`.

Comment: @Issac - I have a pointer to the workoutType.managedObjectContext even at the time save: is being called. I did verify it using a breakpoint.

Comment: @warrenm - I am never getting any error. It always goes to the else block and 'No error' is logged in the debug console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a default value set for that attribute in your model?

There is an identified bug in Core Data where in some situations (I have not narrowed it all the way down) where an attribute with a default value gets reset several times during the backgrounding of an application.

The way to test for this is to listen for the value being changed via KVO and log the changes then duplicate your test.  If you see several changes then you know you are hitting that bug.

The only known solution I have seen that is reliable is to remove the default value.  If a default value is required then I would add it to the `NSManagedObject` subclass in the `-awakeFromInsert` method and then update the validation methods to check for it.  Sucks I know.

### Update #2

How many contexts do you have?

Are you using parent child contexts?

If so, are you saving the top most parent?

### Update #3

Ok, a `UIManagedDocument` has two `NSManagedObjectContext` instances inside of it.  Is there a reason you are using a `UIManagedDocument`?  Do you have more than one document in your application?  If you don't then I strongly suggest you switch back to a traditional Core Data stack.  The `UIManagedDocument` is not really meant to be in a single stack application.

As for the saving issue directly, `UIManagedDocument` tries to save in the background when you exit the application.  If can take a bit of time and, personally, is not very reliable.  You can request a save on exit which will help to insure the save is speedy, but even then it can be unreliable.

How are you exiting the application?

Are you killing it in Xcode?

Are you backgrounding it and then resuming it?

Are you backgrounding it and then killing it from the iOS device?

You can listen for the `UIManagedDocument` to save and then print a log statement so you can see when the saves actually happen to disk.  That might be useful to help narrow down exactly when it is and is not saving.

Comment: The attribute (a Boolean actually) does not have a default value. The problem is happening with all other attributes (strings) as well. I tried to observe the changes to it using KVO. There are multiple notifications being sent every time I change it (though the changes being reported are correct!). The no. of notifications being reported increase every time I change it! - http://i45.tinypic.com/e71a4h.png

Comment: Edit to previous comment of mine - Multiple notifications were coming due to a mistake of mine. Corrected it. There is just one notification coming every time a change is made.

Comment: There is just 1 context I have. A UIManagedDocument is created in View Controller 1. I get it's context and use it to retrieve all the data through fetched results controller. When a row is tapped, I segue to next view controller (all in a navigation controller) and pass its associated NSManagedObject as well in prepareForSegue. I did verify by doing a NSLog on the context being used in each of the view controllers. They all show the same context with NSLog.

Comment: And what I didn't tell is that some times (very very few times, perhaps when I am not quitting the application soon after making the changes), the same code worked. The data did get stored in the disk as it was reflected next time when I launched the app. But, very few times.

Comment: I changed my code and used a traditional Core Data stack. Am just not interacting with UIManagedDocument any more and so far it seems to be working. I am really unsure what is the reason UIManagedDocument did not work reliably. Perhaps some later day, I will try to debug it again. Thanks for all your help Marcus.

Answer (score 1):

I think you shouldn't use saving on context, the document will auto save.

There might be a data consistency error when the document is being saved. I propose to you not to use saving of the context by `[self.workoutType.managedObjectContext save:&error]` and use the following class inherited from `UIManagedDocument` which adds logging on auto-save:

LoggingManagedDocument.h:

```
@interface LoggingManagedDocument : UIManagedDocument

@end
```

LoggingManagedDocument.m:

```
#import "LoggingManagedDocument.h"

@implementation LoggingManagedDocument

- (id)contentsForType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)outError
{
    NSLog(@"Auto-Saving Document");
    return [super contentsForType:typeName error:outError];
}

- (void)handleError:(NSError *)error userInteractionPermitted:(BOOL)userInteractionPermitted
{
    NSLog(@"error: %@ userInfo: %@", error, error.userInfo);
}

@end
```

This class should help you identify the problem, why your data is not saved. Just let the application run and wait 15-30 seconds after you make the change of the attribute and auto-save should occur.

The logging is based on: http://blog.stevex.net/2011/12/uimanageddocument-autosave-troubleshooting/

Comment: Thanks Marian, will give it a shot. But mate, waiting for 15-30 seconds is not the thing to settle with!

Comment: Waiting 15-30 seconds (might be more, it's not specified when auto-save will happen) should not be a problem. It is totally transparent - application will see the changes immediately, and data will be auto-saved when appropriate. If you really want to save yourself, use UIDocument methods to save the document as Jorge Ortiz suggested. If you don't like the way it works, switch back to a traditional Core Data stack as Marcus S. Zarra suggested.

Comment: I reverted to using a traditional Core Data stack, it is working. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks a bunch Marian. I had an error with auto saving that was driving me crazy because I couldn't figure out what was happening and your logging subclass helped me pinpoint it.

Answer (score 0):

From the UIManageDocument documentation:

> The UIManagedDocument architecture leads to several considerations:
>
> You should typically use the standard UIDocument methods to save the document.
>   If you save the child context directly, you only commit changes to the parent context and not to the document store. If you save the parent context directly, you sidestep other important operations that the document performs.

The easiest option is to use a saveless model, which means using the NSUndoManager of the document. I usually do

```
[self.workoutType.managedObjectContext.undoManager beginUndoGrouping];
```

before adding the changes and

```
[self.workoutType.managedObjectContext.undoManager endUndoGrouping];
```

after editing.

Comment: This didn't seem to make any difference Jorge. But, thanks for your help nevertheless. I just reverted to using a traditional Core Data stack.

Answer (score 0):

**You need to save the document:**

```
[document saveToURL:document.fileURL forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForOverwriting completionHandler:NULL];
```